# Create a bootable USB drive without using the entire drive

Tags: usb-flash-drive, rufus

I'm trying to create a bootable USB drive using Rufus. My USB drive is a 64GB Sandisk that has around 40GB of files that I cannot transfer elsewhere. Can I somehow create a bootable USB using only the remaining free space and not have to delete the other files on it?

Comment: While not strictly support, you should be able to create multiple partitions on the flash drive, allowing you to put data on the secondary partition.  This will require you to move the files off the drive, partition and image the drive in question, and then move the data back to the partition.  However, by using Rufus, you are at the mercy of whatever it's programmed to do.  Which means you will have to move the files off the drive, image the the drive with Rufus, then shrink the partition allowing multiple partitions on the drive. I have done this in the past for flash cards for my Rasp PI.

Comment: Are there any other applications other that Rufus that can do something like this?

Comment: There are hundreds of applications that can make bootable media.  Rufus is just a well known application.  I won't be able to suggest any particular application.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I disable Rufus' automatic partitioning of unallocated space?](https://superuser.com/questions/1358953/how-do-i-disable-rufus-automatic-partitioning-of-unallocated-space)

Comment: As @Ramhound mentions, you'll need to move the files elsewhere, at least temporarily. Though theoretically it is *sometimes* possible to shrink an existing partition and use the freed space for other purposes, 1. The new partition would likely not be bootable. 2. While reallocating space, existing files could be damaged.